# issues with resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf

I was tinkering with my `resolv.conf` file. I logged in to root and made the changes to it there. All of a sudden, I cannot get through to any websites using my Firefox browser.

The file looks like this

```
#Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Can someone please help me fix this!

Comment: If you broke the resolv.conf file, issuing a `service NetworkManager restart` should fix the problem. NetworkManager generates the resolv.conf if you have NM installed, which is what it looks like to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications read `/etc/resolv.conf` when they start. If you've changed that file, you may need to restart applications that access the network. Restart Firefox.

To avoid this inconvenience, you can run a local DNS caching proxy, put `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` to point applications at your proxy, and configure your proxy however you like. This has the added benefit of making DNS requests faster. [Dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is a popular choice. See [No DNS on Debian wifi after unplugging the DNS cable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67295/no-dns-on-debian-wifi-after-unplugging-the-dns-cable/67501#67501) and [Process calling getaddrinfo() at boot gets permanently stuck with bad /etc/resolv.conf?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89699/process-calling-getaddrinfo-at-boot-gets-permanently-stuck-with-bad-etc-resol/89816#89816) for examples.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked. I changed my resolv.conf to point to 127.0.0.1 and getting dnsmasq to point to a custom nameserver file fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Rebooting would be the simplest way to have the resolv.conf file automatically fixed.

As a couple of comments rightly state, there are definitely more subtle ways to have the file reconstructed, however, they are distribution dependent:

You might check which one match yours, if any:

```
service network-manager restart      # Debian/Ubuntu/Mint
/etc/init.d/network restart          # Suse
/sbin/service NetworkManager restart # RedHat/Fedora
/etc/rc.d/rc.inet1 restart           # Slackware
```

Comment: I would say that even restarting the network interface in question ought to clear things up.

Comment: That is indeed the side effect of rebooting I was suggesting under the lines. The idea is people are much more likely to know how to reboot than how to restart an interface.